# How can I get a call stack listing in Perl?

Tags: perl, stack-trace, callstack

Is there a way I can access (for printout) a list of sub + module to arbitrary depth of sub-calls  preceding a current position in a Perl script?

I need to make changes to some Perl modules (.pm's). The workflow is initiated from a web-page thru a cgi-script, passing input through several modules/objects ending in the module where I need to use the data. Somewhere along the line the data got changed and I need to find out where.

Comment: While this does not answer your question it might help you solve your problem :-) Here is an interesting article describing one way how to figure out who changes your variables from [Mark Dominus](http://blog.plover.com/oops/who-farted.html)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use [Devel::StackTrace](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-StackTrace/).

```
use Devel::StackTrace;
my $trace = Devel::StackTrace->new;
print $trace->as_string; # like carp
```

It behaves like Carp's trace, but you can get more control over the frames.

The one problem is that references are stringified and if a referenced value changes, you won't see it.  However, you could whip up some stuff with [PadWalker](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PadWalker/) to print out the full data (it would be huge, though).

Comment: A very useful alternative: `perl -d:Confess script.pl` from [Devel::Confess](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Confess).

Answer (score 25):

This code works **without any additional modules**.
Just include it where needed.

```
my $i = 1;
print STDERR "Stack Trace:\n";
while ( (my @call_details = (caller($i++))) ){
    print STDERR $call_details[1].":".$call_details[2]." in function ".$call_details[3]."\n";
}
```

Comment: start at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 20):

`Carp::longmess` will do what you want, and it's standard.

```
use Carp qw<longmess>;
use Data::Dumper;
sub A { &B; }
sub B { &C; }
sub C { &D; }
sub D { &E; }

sub E { 
    # Uncomment below if you want to see the place in E
    # local $Carp::CarpLevel = -1; 
    my $mess = longmess();
    print Dumper( $mess );
}

A();
__END__
$VAR1 = ' at - line 14
    main::D called at - line 12
    main::C called at - line 10
    main::B called at - line 8
    main::A() called at - line 23
';
```

I came up with this sub (Now with optional blessin' action!)

```
my $stack_frame_re = qr{
    ^                # Beginning of line
    \s*              # Any number of spaces
    ( [\w:]+ )       # Package + sub
    (?: [(] ( .*? ) [)] )? # Anything between two parens
    \s+              # At least one space
    called [ ] at    # "called" followed by a single space
    \s+ ( \S+ ) \s+  # Spaces surrounding at least one non-space character
    line [ ] (\d+)   # line designation
}x;

sub get_stack {
    my @lines = split /\s*\n\s*/, longmess;
    shift @lines;
    my @frames
        = map { 
              my ( $sub_name, $arg_str, $file, $line ) = /$stack_frame_re/;
              my $ref =  { sub_name => $sub_name
                         , args     => [ map { s/^'//; s/'$//; $_ } 
                                         split /\s*,\s*/, $arg_str 
                                       ]
                         , file     => $file
                         , line     => $line 
                         };
              bless $ref, $_[0] if @_;
              $ref
          } 
          @lines
       ;
    return wantarray ? @frames : \@frames;
}
```

Comment: longmess is no longer a documented or automatically exported feature of Carp.  However:

    `my $mess = carp();`

will provide similar but not identical behaviour.

Answer (score 18):

[caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) can do that, though you may want even more information than that.

Answer (score 16):

There's also `Carp::confess` and `Carp::cluck`.

Answer (score 4):

In case you can't use (or would like to avoid) non-core modules, here's a simple subroutine I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub printstack {
    my ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine, $hasargs, $wantarray, $evaltext, $is_require, $hints, $bitmask, $hinthash);
    my $i = 1;
    my @r;
    while (@r = caller($i)) {
        ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine, $hasargs, $wantarray, $evaltext, $is_require, $hints, $bitmask, $hinthash) = @r;
        print "$filename:$line $subroutine\n";
        $i++;
    }
}

sub i {
    printstack();
}

sub h {
    i;
}

sub g {
    h;
}

g;
```

It produces output like as follows:

```
/root/_/1.pl:21 main::i
/root/_/1.pl:25 main::h
/root/_/1.pl:28 main::g
```

Or a oneliner:

```
for (my $i = 0; my @r = caller($i); $i++) { print "$r[1]:$r[2] $r[3]\n"; }
```

You can find documentation on caller [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html).

Answer (score 3):

One that is more pretty: [Devel::PrettyTrace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::PrettyTrace)

```
use Devel::PrettyTrace;
bt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Moving [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229009/how-can-i-get-a-call-stack-listing-in-perl#comment87243409_229030) to an answer:

1. Install [Devel::Confess](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Confess) the [right way](https://cpan.metacpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html)

   ```
   cpanm Devel::Confess
   ```
2. Run with

   ```
   perl -d:Confess myscript.pl
   ```

On errors, this will show the whole call stack list.