# How do I force a stack backtrace for all fatal errors in Perl?

Tags: perl

In Perl, is there a way to force all fatal errors to display a stack backtrace like `Carp::confess` produces?

I know you can do `use warnings FATAL => 'all';` to make warnings fatal over the current lexical scope.

Further it is possible to use `$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { CORE::die(@_) };` to make all warnings fatal everywhere (that hasn't localized the SIGWARN handler).

Is there a clean way to do this, or do I need to tweak SIGDIE?  And if I do write a SIGDIE handler, what is the best way to get the trace?

An ideal solution would work with the standard testing libraries, `Test::More` and friends.

**Update:** Mark Johnson suggests using a SIGDIE handler to call `Carp::confess`.  It works nicely.  Here's the code:

```
use Carp;
$SIG{ __DIE__ } = \&Carp::confess;
```

Comment: Same question, more answers: [How can I replace all 'die's with 'confess' in a Perl application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1877638/269126)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install a SIGDIE handler that calls Carp::confess?  Or just set up Carp::confess as the handler for DIE?

Beware of the [standard gotchas](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=SIGDIE) related to eval.  There is an even [weirder gotcha](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=315182) with regard to BEGIN blocks.  Also note the [ominous warning in perlvar](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=747179).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229009/how-can-i-get-a-call-stack-listing-in-perl) for more information on generating stack traces.

Answer (score 12):

See also the module "[Carp::Always](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Carp-Always)", which turns all dies and warns in your code to stacktraces.