# Getting stack traces in Perl?

Tags: perl, stack-trace

How do I get stack traces in Perl?

Comment: `perl -d script.pl`
`DB<1> t 50`
`Trace = on (to level 51)`
`DB<2> T`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are many useful, core and CPAN based tools to generate a stack trace (as other answers illustrate.)  However, if you want to roll your own, check out the [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) builtin.  You can use this to walk down the stack and see exactly what's happening.

Comment: Uh, or use `Devel::StackTrace`.

Comment: That's a fine, other option.  But it requires an external module, which a may or may not find appealing.  Why not just post that as an answer, instead of downvoting?

Comment: You can find an example of using `caller` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56596630/52499).

Answer (score 38):

For debugging needs, I like [Carp::Always](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Carp-Always/).

```
perl -MCarp::Always my_script.pl
```

Comment: I seem to need to do -MCarp=verbose

Answer (score 35):

`Carp::confess` (from `use Carp;`) will give you a full stack trace as part of the error.  If you just need it as part of something failing, `confess` is all you really need.

Per comments, here's output of various `Carp` functions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp qw/longmess cluck confess/;

sub foo {
  &bar;
}

sub bar {
   &baz;
}

sub baz {
   shift->();
}

my %tests = (
    'longmess' => sub { print longmess 'longmess' },
    'cluck'    => sub { cluck 'using cluck' },
    'confess'  => sub { confess 'using confess' },
);

while (my ($name, $sub) = each %tests) {
    print "$name - before eval:\n";
    eval {
        foo($sub);
    };
    print "$name - before if:\n";
    if ($@) {
        print "caught: $@";
    }
    print "$name - done\n\n";
}
```

Running this script, you get:

```
longmess - before eval:
longmess at - line 14
        main::baz called at - line 10
        main::bar called at - line 6
        main::foo('CODE(0x183a4d0)') called at - line 26
        eval {...} called at - line 25
longmess - before if:
longmess - done

confess - before eval:
confess - before if:
caught: using confess at - line 20
        main::__ANON__() called at - line 14
        main::baz called at - line 10
        main::bar called at - line 6
        main::foo('CODE(0x183a3e0)') called at - line 26
        eval {...} called at - line 25
confess - done

cluck - before eval:
using cluck at - line 19
        main::__ANON__() called at - line 14
        main::baz called at - line 10
        main::bar called at - line 6
        main::foo('CODE(0x183a434)') called at - line 26
        eval {...} called at - line 25
cluck - before if:
cluck - done
```

Running this script but redirecting STDOUT (thus showing what gets printed on STDERR), you get:

```
using cluck at - line 19
        main::__ANON__() called at - line 14
        main::baz called at - line 10
        main::bar called at - line 6
        main::foo('CODE(0x183a434)') called at - line 26
        eval {...} called at - line 25
```

Comment: That sends the stack trace and error to STDERR; if you need to capture it, directly use the underlying Carp::longmess().
And Carp::cluck is like confess but dies afterwards.

Comment: I think that's backwards -- `cluck` is a warn with a stack trace and `confess` is a die.

Answer (score 14):

Easy way using `caller`.
This code does not use any additional module. Just include it where needed.

```
my $i = 1;
print "Stack Trace:\n";
while ( (my @call_details = (caller($i++))) ){
  print $call_details[1].":".$call_details[2]." in function ".$call_details[3]."\n";
}
```

Comment: While this snippet works great, I think it makes sense to swap `$call_details[1].":".$call_details[2]` (caller) and `$call_details[3]` (callee) in the output.