# Perl warning printed without 'use warnings' or -w in any files

Tags: ajax, apache, perl, cgi, mod-perl

I have a lot of old Perl code that gets called frequently, I have been writing a new module and all of a sudden I'm getting a lot of warnings in my error_log for Apache, they are for every module currently being used. e.g,

```
"my" variable $variable masks earlier declaration in same statement at
    /path/to/module.pm line 40 (#1)

Useless use of hash element in void context at
    /path/to/another/module.pm line 212 (#2)
```

The main layout of the codebase is one giant script that includes the modules and directs the requests to them needed to create certain pages for the website and the main script then handles static elements like menus.

My current project is separated from this main script and doesn't use it however any time I call my code using ajax, there are some other ajax calls that will use the main script and the warnings only seem to appear from those request but only when I'm calling my project.

I have grepped every module and none of them have use warnings (or -w) in them, I have also tried using no warnings 'all' in the main script and my own project but it's not doing anything.

At this point I'm out of ideas on what to do next so all help is appreciated, I'd just like to suppress the warnings, the codebase is quite old and poorly written so going and correcting each issue that causes the warns in the first place isn't do-able.

The Apache server is running mod_perl as well, if that might make a difference I have a feeling it might be something to do with CGI, but I can't seem to find any evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that the code gets called by running certain top-level Perl script(s).

Then use the `__WARN__` hook in those script(s) to stop printing of warnings

```
BEGIN { $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {} };
```

Place this `BEGIN` block before the `use` statements so to affect modules as well.

An empty subroutine is the way to mute warnings since `__WARN__` doesn't support `'IGNORE'`.

See [warn](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html) and [`%SIG` in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%SIG). 
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40114084/4653379) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44011471/4653379) for comments and some examples.

---

To investigate further and track the warnings you can use [Carp](https://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html)

```
BEGIN {
    $SIG{__WARN__} = \&Carp::cluck;  # or Carp::confess; to also die
}
```

which will make it print full stack traces. This can be fine-tuned as you please since we can write our own sub to be called. Or use [Carp::Always](http://search.cpan.org/~ferreira/Carp-Always-0.13/lib/Carp/Always.pm).

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43061904/4653379)
for some more drastic measures (like overriding [CORE::GLOBAL::warn](http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html))

Once you find a more precise level at which to suppress warnings then `local $SIG{__WARN__}` is the way to go, if possible. This is used in a post linked above, and here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758909/ipcrun-detection-of-premature-child-exit-and-closed-pipes/44776266#44776266). It is of course far better to suppress warnings only where needed instead of everywhere.

More detail

- [Getting stack traces in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367807/4653379)
- [How can I get a call stack listing in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229009/how-can-i-get-a-call-stack-listing-in-perl)

Note that `longmess` is unfortunately no longer so standard and well supported.

Comment: Hmm didn't seem to work when I implemented it into the main file, however 
it did work when I implemented it into my project, going to mark this as solved and I should hopefully be able to locate what's causing it from here. Cheers.

Comment: Great.  I was just about to relax the "in the main program" statement, since I don't understand the structure of the project. Thank you for the attribution.

Comment: @Fashim Updated, this is what I meant.  I hope it's better.  In order to track it you can change the warning to a `die` (see one of the linked posts) and then print a full stack trace.  I'll add a comment on that to the post.

Comment: @Fashim  Added ideas on how to try to track where the warnings fire from

Comment: Ahh wonderful, thank you so much and sorry about the vague description the code is really terrible.