# Replacing `close` with `open` `/dev/null`?

Tags: file, perl, fork, stdout, stderr

We have such Perl code:

```
if (fork==0) {
  # in child process close STDOUT и STDERR, for the parent process didn't wait a response from the child and finished quickly
  close(STDOUT); 
  if (!defined fileno(CGI::Carp::SAVEERR)) {close(STDERR)} # TODO learn to close redirected STDERR
  else        { close(CGI::Carp::SAVEERR); } 

  # ...
}
```

We had the problem described in [Perl: STDOUT reopened as FH only for input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45786094/856090) - To solve it I was recommended not to close STDOUT and instead to reopen it as '/dev/null'.

Should I replace in the above code ALL calls of `close` with `open` `/dev/null`? or only `close(STDOUT)` and `close(STDERR)`?

Won't this replacement break "parent process didn't wait a response from the child and finished quickly"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be a few things to clear up.

The parent does need to *reap* its child processes (`wait` or `waitpid` on `SIGCHLD`), if that is what you mean by "*wait a response from the child*".  However, if parent exits first the child is re-parented by `init` and all is well. This is not affected by the child's closing (reopening) of its streams.

As for "closing" the streams, they should be redirected (reopened) to `/dev/null` instead.  See, for instance, [Complete disassociation of child from parent in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Complete-Dissociation-of-Child-from-Parent) for how the streams are shut down for daemonization, and [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787171/4653379) in the post linked in the question.

Finally, it appears that `STDERR` was [saved and redirected to a file in `CGI::Carp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Carp.html#REDIRECTING-ERROR-MESSAGES). Whether you now want to close or restore it is up to intent/design. If the log to which `STDERR` is going and the stream itself should be closed you should first close the log, on what the module should restore `STDERR` (check please), and then redirect the stream to `/dev/null`.

Altogether, perhaps

```
my $pid = fork // die "Can't fork: $!";  #/

if ($pid == 0) 
{
    open STDOUT, '>', '/dev/null' or die "Can't write to /dev/null: $!";

    if (defined(fileno(CGI::Carp::SAVEERR)) 
    {
        close $fh_log_to_which_STDERR_was_redirected  or die $!;
        close CGI::Carp::SAVEERR                      or die $!;
    }    
    open STDERR, '>', '/dev/null' or die "Can't write to /dev/null: $!";
    ...
}
```

but check your `CGI::Carp` handling since there is no information on that in the question.

Context of `fork` isn't given but consider [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/IPC-Run3-0.048/lib/IPC/Run3.pm) or [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.96/lib/IPC/Run.pm) to launch and manage processes.