# Is there an easy way for a perl program to know its nesting level?

Tags: perl, debugging

I am familiar with the [caller](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) function which can be used by a program to know where it was invoked, from which file, package etc.  Is there an easy way for a program to know how deeply nested the caller was?  The use case would be to add some debugging lines without having to explicitly count the nesting level.

I am not looking for a Stack Trace.  I am trying to find how deeply nested a calling function is within the scope of another function.

For example:

```
sub my_debug {
    my ($txt) = @_;
    my ($package, $filename, $line) = caller;
    # Is there a way to know how deeply nested the caller is?
    my $level = ... # How to get this?
    print "DEBUG: You are calling from package $package in $filename "
        . "line $line nesting level $level: MSG: $txt\n";
}

sub badly_nested {
    for my $i ( 1..10 ) {
        # 1-level deep
        for my $j ( 1 .. 10 ) {
            # 2-levels deep
            my_debug( "j is $j" );
            for my $k ( 1 .. 10 ) {
                # 3-levels deep
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a call stack listing in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229009/how-can-i-get-a-call-stack-listing-in-perl)

Comment: Thanks @AbhiNickz, but I am looking to know not how many stack frames deep I am (what Stack Trace will tell you), but how many levels of nesting ( `if ... { if ... { if ... { for ... {    } } } }`.  In python, you could count the leading spaces and divide by the indent amount to figure this out.

Comment: I may be lacking imagination, but I can't see how this information could be useful.

Comment: Imagine setting a debug flag with higher values for more detail about inner loops

Comment: Since you know the $filename and the $line you could perhaps read the file, get that line and count the number of spaces and print that? (divided by 4 or 2 maybe)

Comment: Indent your code properly and do just like in python

Comment: Sure I could count spaces...I was thinking to perhaps use perltidy on the calling function and parse that, but I was hoping there was a less heavy-handed way of doing it, i.e. something the perl parser stores somewhere...

Comment: @xxfelixxx my comment was kind of "troll" ;) , I just thought about it, but I guess it should work if you make the substraction: number of `{` -  number of `}`  to the point where the function call is

Comment: @Flying_whale That might work on some code, but it would be easily spoiled by quoted strings with `{` or `}` characters in them, so that's going into the I need a Full-Blown Parser route...which was what I was trying to avoid.  The Solution of using Scope::Upper works well, without the need to re-parse anything.

Comment: I wrapped it all into a package, so I can just add debug lines (with hires timing) wherever and then selectively turn them on and off.   https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Scope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Perl module available on CPAN, Scope::Upper will facilitate what you are asking for:

```
use strict;                     
use warnings;                   

use Scope::Upper qw(SCOPE);     

print SCOPE(), "\n";            
{                               
    print SCOPE(), "\n";        
    {                           
        print SCOPE(), "\n";    
        {                       
            print SCOPE(), "\n";
        }                       
        print SCOPE(), "\n";    
    }                           
    print SCOPE(), "\n";        
}                               
print SCOPE(), "\n";
```

The output from this code is:

```
0
1
2
3
2
1
0
```

So it will enable you to see what depth your current scope is, which can be used to deduce how deeply nested loops are.  You can pass an offset to the `SCOPE()` function. So for example, if you called `{SCOPE(1)}` the return value would be zero despite being one scope deep. This could be useful in a situation where you don't care that you're inside of a subroutine or an `if` block, so want to start counting deeper in.  For example:

```
if ($foo) {
    foreach my $x (1..10) {
        foreach my $y (1..10) {
            print SCOPE(1), "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

In this example response will show scope depth to be 2 rather than 3 because passing a 1 to `SCOPE()` hints it to disregard the scope of the `if(){...}` block.