# How can I get the line number and file name of a coderef?

Tags: perl

Say I've got some bit of library code, not entirely unlike this:

```
sub try_hard {
  my $sub = shift;
  my $tries = 3;
  my @failures;
  while($tries--) {
    eval {
      my $success = $sub->(@_) or die "sub returned false value";
      1;
    } or do {
      push @failures, $@;
    }
  }
  die "try_hard: failed 3 times: $failures[-1]"
}
```

This might fail like this:

```
try_hard: failed 3 times: sub returned false value at BadUtils.pm line 7
```

...which is not useful if you're calling `try_hard` in a number of places and you don't know which call was the one that soft-failed.

If I could get the source of `$sub`, I could change that die to:

```
  my $success = $sub->(@_) or die "sub returned false value at $file line $lineno
";
```

and the library would be slightly DWIMmer. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: I realize that it's entirely possible for a coderef to be generated on the fly (e.g. `my $potato = eval "sub { $the_code }"`) and in those cases there might not be a good way to attribute paternity to the coderef. I'm happy to be right some of the time rather than none of the time, however.

Comment: Could you use [`__LINE__`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__LINE__.html) and [`__FILE__`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__FILE__.html) ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland wouldn't those be the `__LINE__` and the `__FILE__` of `try_hard`? checking...

Comment: Yes I guess they would... Maybe you could try [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) then?

Comment: `__LINE__` does not work: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jFQdcbHjC4/

Answer (score 3):

Use `croak` instead of `die`. You can force a backtrace by starting your script using

```
perl -MCarp::Always script
```

or

```
PERL5OPT=-MCarp::Always script
```

Answer (score 2):

[caller](http://p3rl.org/caller):

```
my ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine) = caller(1);
my $success = $sub->(@_) or die "sub returned false value at ".
    "$filename line $line in sub $subroutine in package $package";
```

Also see: [How can I get a call stack listing in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229009)

Comment: ...I guess that would be a useful approximation, if I can't know where `$sub` is I will at least know where the call to `try_hard` is. This will also be more useful should the one `$sub` be `try_hard`ed multiple times.